# Насколько сильно связывать объекты в игре?

Tags: javascript, ооп, разработка-игр, шаблоны-проектирования

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в вопросе организации кода в простейшей игре. и в результате скажите:

1. правильный первый вариант
2. правильный второй вариант
3. оба варианта правильные и используются в зависимости от ситуации
4. давно уже существует паттерн %patternname% и с успехом используется в такой ситуации

Допустим есть 2D-ландшафт, над ним летит корабль игрока. Корабль может стрелять ракетами.

Описываю первый вариант организации ООП-кода на js(в js контроллер и представление совмещены):

инициализация игры начинается с создания spaceView, который в свою очередь инициализирует:

ландшафт,

корабль игрока

PlayerShipView - корабль игрока. Он может стрельнуть ракетой(PlayerRocketView). То есть объект корабля связан с объектом ракеты

Ракета может столкнуться с ландшафтом. То есть объект ракеты связан с объектом spaceView

В результате:

Имеем 3 связанных объекта, но каждый из них содержит только свою функциональность(это плюс).

Но если в программе придётся что-нибудь менять(например отключить кораблю игрока возможность стрелять ракетами), то вносить правки придётся в разных местах программы(это минус).

Есть несколько глобальных переменных(это минус)

Описываю второй вариант организации ООП-кода на js(в js контроллер и представление совмещены):

инициализация игры начинается с создания spaceView, который в свою очередь инициализирует:

ландшафт,

корабль игрока,

ракеты(есть нажата кнопка "огонь")

и вообще все остальные объекты

Таким образом:

Если например игрок нажимает "огонь", то инициализация ракеты происходит в spaceView, а PlayerShipView вообще ничего не знает об объекте ракеты(это плюс).

Соответственно нет глобальных переменных(это плюс).

Но в spaceView содержится куча логики(всей игры, в котрой кроме корабля игрока и ракеты существует очень много других объектов).

Для наглядности я реализовал первый вариант здесь: 
https://github.com/zlodiak/space-1

В нём используются различные библиотечки типа backbone, underscore, но незнание их не мешает пониманию общей структуры программы

Не бейте(ногами), я знаю что вопрос для телепатов

Answer (score 1):

1. Нет ничего плохого в использовании глобального объекта. Незачем создавать объект который по сути будет глобальным объектом.
2. При создании объектов следует применять абстракцию, т.е. выделять их наиболее существенные стороны.